# Change meta description in search result page using add_action / add_filter

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

I trying to change the meta description on single template and page template, and it works.

I trigger to change meta description by using add_action. But when I try to change meta description on search result page, this is not work by using add_action.

Is there any other way to to so? I need using add_action or add_filter because I will trigger the meta description from bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you added this to your header.php

```
<?php if (is_search())
{
//ADD SUM META DESCRIPTIONS
}
?>
```